# Trouble setting up SFML in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I've followed the tutorial over at the SFML main site. It doesn't work. I followed it exactly. Still doesn't work. I've been screwing the linker settings for about 12 hours now. I'm new at this. And needless to say I'm quite frustrated.

I'm getting a slew of undefined referenced errors nearly identical to this.

```
C:/Users/Tim/Desktop/cocks/SFLM Project/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you show the includes you made in your `main.cpp` and your linker settings ? Are you compiling in debug or release mode ?

Comment: Is your library the same version as in the tutorial? It could be the case your version is older and hence linking problems occur.

Comment: My includes - #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp> - Now my linker settings - sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics - I assume release mode. Whatever is default when hitting CTRL-F9

Comment: Are you sure the SFML's header is found (have you entered the correct directory in search driectories -> compiler) ? Do you have this `undefined reference to` error for every single use of something under the namespace `sf::` ? Also, don't forget that the linker settings have an order of precedence. `sfml-graphics` depends on `sfml-window` which depends on `sfml-system`, so they must be in that exact order.

Comment: Yes they are in order. Yes the error is attached to every sf:: namespace and nothing but that namespace. No errors outside of that namespace. Quick Question. Were should SFML 2.0 be? I have it directly in my C drive. And my in "Search Directories" i have it pointing to the "include" folder of SFML.

Comment: You can place it wherever you want since you provide the good location (and it seems you did, the `include` folder itself containing `SFML` folder) for includes and libs. These errors mean that either the SFML headers cannot be included, or that every call you make to any function/class is erroneous, but the second seems unlikely.

Comment: Add the linking command codeblock's using to your question. It's under *Build log* tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `GCC 4.7 TDM (SJLJ) - 64 bits` then try using `GCC 4.7 MinGW (DW2) - 32 bits`.

I also suffered from same problem and when i switched to the 32 bit version , it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqjNOd1UYtE
check out that video and see if it helps you
I set up this tutorial for using sfml 2.1 but if you're using windows 7 it should work for you